# display partial derivatives in maxima

Tags: maxima

I want to display the partial derivative *df/dx* of **f(x,y) = ln(y-1-x^2)-xy^2**.

A comparable example for what I want is:

```
(%i0) f(x) := x^8$
(%i1) diff(f(x),x);
(%o1) 8*x^7
```

I've tried:

```
(%i1) f(x,y):=ln(y-1-x^2)-xy^2$

(%i2) g(x,y):=(diff(f(x,y), x));
(%o2) g(x,y):='diff(f(x,y),x,1)

(%i3) g(x,y):=''(diff(f(x,y), x));
(%o3) g(x,y):='diff(ln(y-x^2-1),x,1)
```

But it doesn't work (the summand **-xy^2** got deleted?).

I want the derivated function. Something like this:

```
             (2*x)
g(x,y):=  ——————————— - y^2
         (1 + x^2 - y)
```

Comment: Note that the natural logarithm is `log` and not `ln` in Maxima.

Answer (score 3):

the problem with your funciotn is that xy^2 instead of x*y^2for maxima is a variable you should write it as follows:

```
(%i5) f(x,y):=ln(y-1-x^2)-x*y^2;

(\%o5) f\left(x , \linebreak[0]y\right):=\mathrm{ln}\left(y-1-x^2\right)-x\,y^2
(%i6) diff(f(x,y), x);

(\%o6) \ifracd{d}{d\,x}\,\mathrm{ln}\left(y-x^2-1\right)-y^2
```

Comment: Oh my... I probably would not have found it, no matter how long I'd looked at it. 
Thank you!

Comment: If this helped you, please consider to check this answer as valid, thanks